# minus sign comes as postfix of value when set Label.RightToLeft

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, label, right-to-left

When set `RightToLeft.Yes` to label minus sign comes as postfix of value.
Eg : -10 shows as 10-

are there any solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: What language and/or framework is this?

Comment: Hi joachim, it is C# 4.0

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms? Post some code, please

Comment: yes it is windows forms.

lblValue.Text = -10;

Comment: For all I know of Hebrew and Arabic this is correct.  Numbers and western text are left-to-right, everything else is right-to-left.

Comment: It is expected in right-to-left to come as what looks to us like a postfix, I'd say! Are you confusing this with text alignment?

Comment: This is how RightToLeft is suppose to work.

Comment: Thanks all, I know it is how RightToLeft work. I just want to show value as -10 in both Arabic & English modes. i have set all RightToLeft.No for all labels which show values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this to happen you could use TextAlign = Right instead.

Comment: can't do that. because application support for both English and Arabic mode.

Comment: You could create your own label control that inherits from label and remap the RightToLeft property to set the TextAlign property as you see fit.